# Substitute previous row value if value equal to 0 in Python(Can't use drop duplicates)

Tags: python

I want to check if the value of a column in a dataframe is equal to 0 and if it is 0, I want to substitute the previous row's value of that column.

Suppose my data is as follows,

```
a=[0,0,1,2,5,6,0,0,8,9,0,11,0,13]
```

Output should be

```
a=[0,0,1,2,5,6,6,6,8,9,9,11,11,13]
```

I tried the following command,

```
a = a.replace(0, np.NaN).ffill()
```

but I am getting,

```
a=[NaN,NaN,1,2,5,6,6,6,8,9,9,11,11,13]
```

I can't use drop_duplicates because the values would occur again in my array. So I need to check the previous value alone and do the calculation.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
previousValue = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 0:
        a[i] = previousValue
    else:
        previousValue = a[i]
```

Or the more concise way would be

```
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] == 0:
        a[i] = a[i-1]
```

Comment: If I use this, I am getting the following warning and also no changes in the values,

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Is `a` just a regular list? When I run this with a regular list it gives the output you specified.

Comment: It is a dataframe with 5 columns. I posted an example here for easy reproduction. I need to fill the values in one the columns

Comment: Can you compare and assign values like you would with a list? The logic is right, but you might need to change a few details if it's not a default list. You should add some more details in your question about what libraries/data structures you are using.

Comment: Use ``len(a)`` instead of ``len(a[1:])``.